# Arraylist generating first element as null

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have been trying to implement Dijkstra algorithm. The following is the code for reading the input:

```
            System.out.println("Enter the number of Cities ");
            int no_Of_Cities = scannerObj.nextInt();
            List<Vertex> Vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>(no_Of_Cities) ;
            for (int itr = 0; itr < no_Of_Cities; itr++){
                  System.out.println("Enter the details for city "+itr+": ");
                  System.out.println("Name of the vertex: ");
                  String name = new String(scannerObj.nextLine());
                  Vertex vertexObj = new Vertex(name);
                  Vertices.add(vertexObj);
                  }
            display(Vertices);
```

and the display function is as follows:

```
      public static void display(List<Vertex> vertices){
            int length = vertices.size();
            for(int i =0;i<length;i++){
                  System.out.println();
                  System.out.println("Entry for i ="+i+" is: "+vertices.get(i).getName());
            }
      }
```

When I try to execute the code the following is the output I get :

> Enter the number of Cities 
>   3
>
> Enter the details for city 0:
>
> Name of the vertex: 
>   a
>
> Please enter the details for city 1:
>
> Name of the vertex: 
>   b
>
> Please enter the details for city 2:
>
> Name of the vertex: 
>   c
>
> Entry for i =0 is:
>
> Entry for i =1 is: a
>
> Entry for i =2 is: b

Can any one explain where I am making the mistake?

NOTE: The Vertex is another class which holds only the necessary details for vertex like name and edge array.

Comment: Just an off-note: I suggest doing `Integer.parseInt(scannerObj.nextLine())` instead of `scannerObj.nextInt()`

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja - Your way will be more efficient than his current version. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have incorporated your way in my program. :) @TheLostMind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String name = new String(scannerObj.nextLine());**

this line is causing the problem as it is causing the input to skip to the next line thereby skipping the input for city 0.

use this code it will work -:
String name = new String(scannerObj.next());

Comment: Thanks @Puneet the fix that you suggested is working fine but the problem was that the input was getting moved by one index position. In effect the last value was getting lost. Can you please shed some light as to why this was happening ?

Answer (score 3):

Add `scannerObj.nextLine();`

after

`int no_Of_Cities = scannerObj.nextInt();`

This would consume the end of the line that contains the int you just read, and prevent that (empty) line from being used as the next input when you first call `String name = new String(scannerObj.nextLine());`

Comment: I did as you suggested but it did not work the same problem exists the first element is still null